# Moving from one SwiftIUI view to another

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm new to app development and I'm building an app which requires moving across different views.

At the moment, I'm using a NavigationView/link setup, however this means each time I place a NavigationView inside a different view with a NavigationView, the size of the view gets smaller and I'm left with multiple back buttons.

Is there a way to avoid this (a different way to change views in `SwiftUI` without using the Navigation system?)

Comment: You need to post the code. No one can definitively diagnose the problem without it. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that you can get the most from your question.

Answer (score 3):

You should only use one `NavigationView` within your app. For example, at your Home screen of the app?

The `NavigationLink` directs your users to a new view that should **not** have a `NavigationView` view. Adding two `NavigationView`s and linking them together will cause the behaviour you're describing by pushing one `NavigationView` into another shrinking all other views (and themselves) inside.

Try taking all `NavigationView` components away from all other views except your main/root view.

For example:

```
struct ROOT_VIEW: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: SECONDVIEW()) {
                    Text("Show Detail View")
                }.navigationBarTitle("ROOT VIEW")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Link with second view (all other views):

```
struct SECOND_VIEW: View {
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("This is the second view")
                }.navigationBarTitle("ROOT VIEW", display: .inline)
            }
        }
    }
```

Only adding `.navigationBarTitle("ROOT VIEW", display: .inline)` to your second view allows a title to appear at the top (with one back button). You can also add buttons inside each title bar with:

```
.navigationBarItems(leading:
       // FAR LEFT SIDE OF THE TITLE BAR
        HStack {
            Button(action: {// action goes here}) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }.foregroundColor(.pink)
        }, trailing:
       // FAR RIGHT SIDE OF THE TITLE BAR
        HStack {
            Button(action: { //action goes here}) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }.foregroundColor(.blue)
        })
```

### Another Option:

You can direct users between your app without using `NavigationViews`. You can use simple `Boolean states`.

For example, say you had a root view screen, and there were three buttons on the screen, one for logging in, one for registering and one for restting a password, each with their own views. You would only show one view based on a boolean value:

```
struct ROOT_VIEW: View {

    @State var showLogin = true // This will be the default view that gets showed as its default to true
    @State var showRegister = false
    @State var showPasswordReset = false


    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if showLogin{
                LoginView(showLogin: $showLogin, showRegister: $showRegister)
            }
            if showRegister{
                RegisterView()
            }
            if showPasswordReset{
                PasswordResetView()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct LoginView: View {

    @Binding var showLogin: Bool
    @Binding var showRegister: Bool


    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                // Change two bool values to switch to register view (turning off login view and turning on reigster view)
                showLogin.toggle()
                showRegister.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Show Register")
            }.foregroundColor(.pink)
        }
    }
}
```

You would do this to all views that you want the user to go to (obviously). Say you only wanted the `RegisterView` to only be able to go to the `LoginView` and vice versa, you'd only need to provide the `RegisterView` with the the `showLogin` and `showRegister` binding bools in the root view as shown:

RegisterView(showLogin: $showLogin, showRegister: $showRegister)

Make sure in your register view, you don't use a normal `@State` you use a `@Binding` to sync all Boolean values across views.

Comment: Thanks, but I use a Navigation view to go from the home screen (contentview) to a log in page, which works fine. But I also need to change from log in page to a different view, and from that view to another... If there was a different way to change views I wouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Let me add another option for you without the use of NavigationViews.

Comment: I tried this with a new project, and it looks great, however in the LogInView preview section at the bottom I get an error saying "Missing arguments for parameters 'showLogin', 'showRegister' in call".

Comment: Thanks for your help so far though!

Comment: Because you need to provide the preview with the values also using the default values (just show you can see the preview)